# Write custom grammar for Rust macro in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-macros

I use [crepe](https://github.com/ekzhang/crepe) library which provides `crepe!` macro for Datalog-like syntax code. My theme is not working well with it. For example, in the following code:

```rust
crepe! {
    ...
    Edge(x, y) <- Edge(y, x);
}
```

With my current theme VSCode renders `<-` not as a single operator, but rather two different symbols (they have different colors).

I want to fix this behavior by writing grammar plugin for this exact macro. Can I do it and how? Or I can fix this issue in another way?

Comment: Are you using rust-analyzer or just the textmate grammar?

Comment: @PitaJ yes, I use rust-analyzer extension for VSCode.

Comment: Looks like this isn't currently possible with rust-analyzer: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/5389

Comment: @PitaJ thanks for answering! It seems that you are right and my question have no solution until this issue is fixed.